# moss 2007 List Forms - dynamic field logic

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint-2007

I'm using MOSS 2007 for the NewForm.aspx need to implement field logic i.e whether to show certain fields based on the values of preceding fields.

I have implemented a similar solution embedding a Content Editor Webpart within the NewForm.aspx and using JQuery to manipulate the form elements.

However this solution does not lend itself to my current scenario due to the number of fields which need to be referenced. It would make much more sense to somehow wrap div tags around the sections of the form I want to dynamically display rather then reference each field within that section individually.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint's form engine does not have a way to output spaces/panels/divs/groupings within the form as you describe.

If a form is complex, i normally create a web part so i have full control of the fields/layout. Just be aware that the form is detached from the list schema. That means if you add fields to the list schema, then you will have to modify the form. But if you are using jquery, then it effectively is the same.

Or you could customise the form in sharepoint designer.